# Stop and Start controls for jquery innerfade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am trying to control this animation with a stop and start button. Does anyone know how to accomplish this without using the cycle plugin?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(
                function(){


                    $('ul#portfolio').innerfade({
                        speed: 9000,
                        timeout: 5000,
                        type: 'sequence',
                        containerheight: '100%'
                    });



            });
```

link: http://daveywhitney.com/ok/

Comment: I posted an answer here >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758121/controls-for-innerfade ::: It's applicable here as well

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean but theres is a stop() function you can use, and then recall the animation func

Edit: I found [this page](http://www.openstudio.fr/Animated-InnerFade-with-JQuery.html?lang=fr) using the plugin, which very nice, and includes a pause func.  See the example #2, the bgFrame: 'squelettes/img/frame.png' I guess you may like to photoshop some nicer controls, but keep in mind to use the same dimensions, in order to implement it simply and fast.

Comment: I need to control it externally with a start and stop button

Comment: where do you want the button placed? can be over the images anywhere?

Comment: it can be in or around the images