# Controls for InnerFade?

Tags: jquery

I have a slideshow powered by InnerFade, I use innerFade as it handles the mixture of elements within each li much better than other slideshow plugins (img, p etc.).

I'm looking for a solution to be able to add controls to the slideshow, primarily we need pagination, a play/pause button would be nice too.

I'm a javascript novice, jquery is as far as my knowledge extends on the subject. I'd be looking for code examples if possible.

Comment: OK, typically I have found an alternative solution immediately after posting the question. http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/ - I'll post an update if all goes well.

Answer (score 0):

I just love innerfade ( nothing wrong with anythingslider ) but to answer your question, though late, you might like this clone of innerfade >>> https://github.com/wesbaker/jquery.innerFade ::: It has the control's